# htaccess — redirect to www and catch all index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

I'm new to htaccess, so apologies in advance.
I'm trying to redirect all non-www to www. So far so good. At the same time I'm also trying to catch all and clean link ("index.php" not shown) to index.php.

I tried to combine the following lines, but I didn't succeed in make the htaccess work properly:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

It redirects all non-www to www and doesn't show "index.php". But I also want to keep the full url.

Example:

`example.com/subfolder` should link to `www.example.com/subfolder` but show index.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could I understand that you want trailing `index.php` to all of your URLs that points to default index. i.e `www.example.com/subfolder` to be `www.example.com/subfolder/index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

I (hopefully) answered my own question by trial and error.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Of course with the RewriteEngine on